# laravel apache directory permissions

Tags: permissions, apache-2.4

So, I'm beyond perplexed! I just spun up a new RHEL 7.2 instance on AWS. I successfully installed Apache, MariaDB, & PHP. Then I successfully installed Laravel 5. Everything worked and is working great...except for one ridiculously small hitch that is driving me bonkers!

- So, my Apache is running as U:G (apache:apache)
- My new Laravel site has been chown'd all too apache:apache
- Directory permissions have been set to 777 for the storage directory recursively.

Yet my system continues to throw permission denied fatal errors when trying to write to the storage/logs directory or when trying to run the file_put_contents function to the storage/framework/views directory.

I have opened those directories up wide open with 777 and still it's doing this.

HELP?!

P.S. "This is server related...so, please don't shut down my question for that reason."

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix my issue, but I am not in the least bit happy with the fix. I disabled selinux! So, the upside here is that I now know that it is selinux that was the cause...now, how to resolve so I can turn it back on. I don't like running a production server with that disabled.